# Optimizing LINQ query for trim and remove

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following query which is returning an array at the end .

```
 orderArray = orderValue.Split(',').Select(x =>
                                               x.Remove(0, x.IndexOf('_') + 1)
                                                        ).
                                     Select(x => x.Trim(quotes)).ToArray();
```

But I think there is a better way than using multiple selects  to be

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could apply the `Trim` directly:

```
orderArray = orderValue.Split(',')
    .Select(x => x.Remove(0, x.IndexOf('_') + 1).Trim(quotes))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do `.Select(x =>x.Remove().Trim())` in one go...